# How vimdiff links to vim

Tags: vimdiff

When i do a `ls -l /usr/bin/vimdifff` it shows following

```
/usr/bin/vimdiff -> vim
```

Does this mean `vimdiff` and `vim` are the same?

I know that we can use vim for diff by giving `-d`. But how does linking like this makes the `vim` work as a difftool.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315812/70524, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440987/70524

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vim` binary is able to answer by many names and it will tweak its behavior based on which name it is called.

This is a somewhat common practice in Unix, where a program will support checking the name by which it's invoked and will behave differently depending on that name.

At installation time, a single binary will be copied, but symbolic links or hardlinks will be created to make it available under all possible names.

In case of `vim`, it actually supports being called under quite a variety of names. You can see a comprehensive list under [`:help vim-arguments`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#vim-arguments):

> The startup mode can be changed by using another name instead of `vim`, which is equal to giving options:
>
> - `ex` (`vim -e`): Start in Ex mode.
> - `exim` (`vim -E`): Start in improved Ex mode.
> - `view` (`vim -R`): Start in read-only mode.
> - `gvim` (`vim -g`): Start the GUI.
> - `gex` (`vim -eg`): Start the GUI in Ex mode.
> - `gview` (`vim -Rg`): Start the GUI in read-only mode.
> - `rvim` (`vim -Z`): Like `vim`, but in restricted mode.
> - `rview` (`vim -RZ`): Like `view`, but in restricted mode.
> - `rgvim` (`vim -gZ`): Like `gvim`, but in restricted mode.
> - `rgview` (`vim -RgZ`): Like `gview`, but in restricted mode.
> - `evim` (`vim -y`): Easy Vim: set `'insertmode'`.
> - `eview` (`vim -yR`): Like `evim` in read-only mode.
> - `vimdiff` (`vim -d`): Start in diff mode.
> - `gvimdiff` (`vim -gd`): Start in diff mode.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is done via the 0th parameter (e.g., `argv[0]` in C or `$0` in sh)